# Regex to find delimiter and qualifier in csv string (java)

Tags: java, regex, csv, delimiter

Im trying to come up with a regex in java that can be used to extract the used delimiter and qualifier characters in a given csv string. My idea was that instead of matching the wole string Ill just look for the last field, so in pseudocode my regex would look like this:

```
(match as much of beginning as possible) folowed by
Option 1: (delimiter)(qualifier)(any character)*?(qualifier)(end of string|any linebreak character)
Option 2: (delimiter)((?!reference to delimiter capturing group)[any character])*?(qualifier)(end of string|any linebreak character)
```

And the regex I came up wih:

```
([\s\S])*((\W)(?!\3)(\W)[\s\S]*?\4($|\R))|((\W)((?!\7)[\s\S])*?($|\R))
```

Where group 3 is the delimiter, group 4 the qualifier and group 7 the dlimiter of option 2.

[regex 101 link with nonworking example](https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/9809)

Is my concept already wrong or only my regex?

Edit: As pointed out in a comment there can be ambigious lines, but the regex doesnt have to 100% find the delimiter/qualifier on a single try. Im fine with a regex that scans multiple lines to get the result. Also this is to be used in a program where the user defines a simple definition of the data he wants to import (which doesnt include the delimiter/qualifier). Specifically the number of fields, which can be used to test which (of the found) delimiters is the right one if there isnt a clear answer after even multiple lines.

Comment: Are you trying to determine what is separator in CSV? That may be hard if not impossible task. For instance if you have `123,yes|no` what is separator? is it `,` or `|`.

Comment: @Pshemo My understanding was that the qulifier only gets used if you use either the qualfier itself or the delimiter in a field. So in your example Id say , is the delimiter and " is the qulifier, which means "yes"|"no" wold be one field. Or is my udestanding about the use of the qualifier already wrong? Edit: When I wrote this the original string I replied to was: " 123,"yes"|"no". And regarding the the edited ersion without quotes you could look a multiple lines to figure that out, which you would anyway since Id have scan through the lines until I find the qualiier too anyway.

Comment: The delimiting character in a _comma separated values_ file is, by [definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), comma. If a different character is used and the file format does not follow a specific definition, any character could be used. In @Pshemo's example, the delimiter could also be `y` or `3`. If you cannot know the delimiter in advance, you can look for common delimiters like `,`,`;`,`|` and see if the resulting values make any sense. If you know the values' format in advance, you can try to find single characters that separate correctly formatted values.

Comment: @danzel Regarding y or 3 being the delimiter I assumed only non-word characters [(^a-zA-Z0-9_]) could be delimiters. The point in about the finding the character that seperates correctly formatted values is good, and Ill try that if I dont fnd the solution in my original way.

Comment: @goldarm since there is no universal definition of delimiter separated values, everyone can come up with their own delimiter. And since most DSV files are named `.csv`, even if the delimiter is not comma, there is no universal way to find out the delimiter (and even the line delimiter could be different from CR/LF), assuming no prior knowledge. Of course, `y` is unlikely to be the delimiter. If you know the line delimiter, and if you can assume that each line has the same number of values, you could search for characters that have the same number of occurrences in each line.